# How to send complex types via Zend_Soap_Client?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I want to call a webservice using Zend_Soap_Client. This is the relevant code:

```
    $params = new stdClass();
    $params->transactionId = $transactionId;
    $params->transactionState = $transactionState;
    $params->details = $transactionDetails;
    var_dump($params->details);
    try {
        $this->_soapClient->updateTransaction($params);
    }
```

The problem is with the `details` parameter, which is a complex type in the WSDL. `$transactionDetails` contains an array with the (non-empty) elements of the complex type, and this is visible in the `var_dump()`. Previously, I tried using a PHP class with the elements as properties. In both cases, what the SOAP client actually sends is this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:UpdateTransactionRequest>
        <transactionId>45</transactionId>
        <transactionState>SUCCESS</transactionState>
        <details/>
    </ns1:UpdateTransactionRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I think the cause of the problem is that the complexType declared for the parmeter is a base type, of which several extension types exist in the WSDL, and I want to use one of those extension types. I guess Zend_Soap_Client does not recognize any elements that are not present in the base type, which is all of them. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in the standard PHP SOAP client, which Zend_Soap_Client extends. The [`SoapVar`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php) class allows you to wrap a parameter and specify the actual type to use. What I had to do is go back to using a PHP class for `$transactionDetails` and this code:

```
$params->details = new SoapVar($transactionDetails, 
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, get_class($transactionDetails), $namespace);
```